# Arduino micro - stops working using an empty class (ide v 1.8.9)

Tags: c++, arduino

I was busy working on a project (containing many classes) when suddently the arduino became unresponsive

I simplified the project to figure what was causing this

basicaly, one empty C++ class is added to the project

from the moment that class is instanciated staticaly or simply declared as a pointer, the arduino - once programmed - disappear as an usb device

I have to reset it to program it again, here is the main code :

```
#include "main.h"
Main* main; // this crashes the arduino
//Main main; // this too

int led = 13; // simple test code from examples

void setup() {
  pinMode(led, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  digitalWrite(led, HIGH);   // turn the LED on (HIGH is the voltage level)
  delay(1000);               // wait for a second
  digitalWrite(led, LOW);    // turn the LED off by making the voltage LOW
  delay(1000);               // wait for a second
}
```

here is the culprit class :

```
#ifndef MAIN_H
#define MAIN_H

class Main
{
public:
  Main();
};

#endif
```

and its implementation :

```
#include "main.h"

Main::Main()
{

}
```

I tried renaming the class too, just in case of conflict
I thought my arduino was fried, I tried with another one, same thing
I use sublime text, I noticed the arduino ide was sometimes out of wack, so I had to restart it

this makes no sens at all

can someone confirm this ? anything wrong with the code ? I feel I miss something really obvious, but I double checked everything

regards

Comment: `Main *main` main() is a reserved name in C and C++

Comment: Shouldn't compiler complain already? avr-gcc doesn't, but with similar problems ( eg. global variable name same as function name), it says  " `redeclared as different kind of symbol` "

Answer (score 0):

apparently, while renaming the class to Main2 (the cpp and h files too) did not work,

renaming the class as systemCore did work

I really don't have any logical explanation for this on , since the compiler does not complain at all

this is quite insane from an engineer point of view, I mean come on !!!